# Refresh on adding many2many in from inline

Tags: django, django-admin

I have inline with many2many field in it. 
After adding new record using add button and popup window for manytomany field, newly added record is not shown in other inlines in the page. Also, if I want to add new inline after it, newly added manytomany record does not exist until page is refreshed. 
Example:

```
class Target(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Task(models.Model):
    targets = models.ManyToManyField(Target)
    section = models.ForeigKey(Section)

class Section(models.Model):
     name = models.TextField()
```

And in admin:

```
class TaskInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Task

class SectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TaskInline,)
```

If I add new Target from TaskInline form, newly added target cannot be seen in other Task inline forms, nor if I add new Task inline.
Is there a way to refresh the page on Target save, or is there any better solution?

Comment: you are looking for API/Ajax calls. [link]https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/